# Pixel Perfect HTML to PDF w/Embedded Fonts?

Tags: html, embedded-fonts, pixel-perfect

I've hit my head against the wall on this one for a while... I'm able to do this with Flash + Fpdf (See http://santaspencil.com/desktop).

However, as Flash isn't well supported on mobile platforms, I feel I need to migrate over to something else (HTML5?).  The only problem I've found is that I can't get embedded fonts in a webpage to look exactly how they do when they are rendered within a PDF... unless I use Flash.

Can this be done?... Can embedded fonts be used with HTML5 in a way that will render a pixel perfect PDF?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to do this is to build a dynamic page on the server side and then use a URLtoPDF server plugin to access the page as a browser UserAgent so the fonts render as they would in your browser, and then it will convert the rendered page into a PDF and spit you back a file URL that you can `wget` and store, download, or print.

Comment: And yes. HTML5 on that particular page will render the fonts perfectly. This method also gives you a way to see your page rendered before sending it through the PDF converter.